# How to use asyncio.gather with dynamically generated tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, apple-push-notifications, python-asyncio

I have an async method called `send_notifications_async(token)`. This method users a library to sent apple push notifications asynchronously. Given a list of tokens how can I dynamically create a iterable set of tasks to run asynchronously with asyncio.gather?

```
async def gather_notification_responses(tokens):
    return await asyncio.gather(*[send_notification_async(token.token) async for token in tokens])
```

I'm running the code with this synchronous method:

```
def send_notifications(tokens):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    results = loop.run_until_complete(gather_notification_responses(tokens))
    loop.close()
    return results
```

I keep facing the same 2 runtime errors:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

and

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does the code above not work?

Comment: i just updated the description but i keep getting the errors mentioned above

Comment: What is `tokens`? Also, most of `send_notifications` can be replaced with `results = asyncio.run(gather_notification_responses(tokens))`.

Comment: tokens is a list of strings which are device tokens that APNs (apple push notifications service) uses to send notifications to users